# “An unexpected error occurred..." when enabling the Google Apps Marketplace SDK

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

When creating a new Google Apps Console project and enabling the Google Apps Marketplace SDK, after the initial saving of the SDK details all subsequent tries to access the SDK page result in an error: “An unexpected error occurred. We’re looking into this.”

The application is a contextual gadget with a custom extractor, and the problem repeats itself on multiple projects. The first time it happened in an older project, and then a newly created one got the same problem almost immediately after saving the SDK page.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have uncovered one bug but there is a workaround. The Developer Console UI does become broken when you leave the extractor param name or value as empty. These are both required fields. For the param value you can put in a ".*". This used be the same as blank/empty before.

I was able to build this simple COB gadget that worked. You will have to TEST INSTALL as the admin but will likely test the COB gadget as an domain user (recommend you test in separate chrome profile or browser).

Here is my simple spec - https://googledrive.com/host/0B0JNj_IM2wiPb1NaX1B0S29MQlE/helloworldgadget.xml
And I used one of the prebuilt HelloWorld extractor from here - https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets#using_pre-canned_extractors

Let me know if this helps and are able to work around this.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have managed to create a new project and not get the console error anymore, but the app is not visible in Gmail after Test console install, even after testing with multiple accounts/browsers. Since the project has a custom extractor, could that be the problem? For the extractor's URL in the COB extension configuration I have entered <project id>:<extractor id>, is this syntax still valid? I have not changed the extractor's contents at all, and it was working in previous projects.

Comment: @user1978279 FWIW, I didn't get custom extractor to work either :-/

Comment: Let me look into custom extractors separately. Can you start a new question on that with all the details you can share? Thanks!

Comment: Arun, this is the URL : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20679729/gmail-contextual-gadget-doesnt-appear-after-gam-sdk-test-install) Thank you for looking into it.